# Put 10000 small text files to code base, will it make git slow?

Tags: git

In current project, the testers often put all kinds of small text files into code base. Most of them have the size of 10KB, and the amount is increasing everyday. For now, there are more than 6000 files already, I think it will be 10000 in near future.

We feel git are slower and slower. We run git in cygwin, which makes it even slower.

Following are the cost of some operations now:

1. git stash -> more than one minute
2. git pull --rebase -> each commit will spend 1 minute

We waste huge time everyday on basic git operations.

We are looking for the reasons, try to fix it. So I want to know if these small text files are the reason.

If they are the biggest reason, can we fix it by just deleting them? Or we have to delete them in git server(if possible), or create a new git repo?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Cygwin? Git runs pretty well [on Windows without it](http://git-scm.com/downloads) these days.

Comment: @Chris: Does not make much difference though. In this case it's Windows that sucks.

Comment: @Chris One limitation of Git for Windows I ran into recently was the inability to deal with very long filepaths (since Windows has a hard limit on the length of filepaths). Using Cygwin Git was fine, since filepaths will go through a Linux implementation of reading the file system.

Comment: @Chris, customer company has strict IT policy. We are not allowed to install git on windows, only allow to use cygwin, and the git from cygwin

Answer (score 3):

**There is no reason to remove them from version control, not even mentioning removing them from history.**

Git itself is fast with order of magnitude more files than that. The component that slows you down is the operating system. Windows just plain suck when it comes to enumerating files on the disk. And unfortunately Cygwin is only making things worse here, because to provide full Unix compatibility it has to do extra system calls that would not be needed if Windows api was used.

Git needs to enumerate the files and find their modification times each time you run status, which is also included in commit. It is also done in some cases of shell completion.

The good news is that you can tell git not to look for a change in specific files. If you don't need to modify the files, you can simply tell git to not check their timestamps with

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path...
```

The files will still be there and you can even still modify them, just when you do, you have to explicitly call `git add` on them, because git won't notice the change otherwise.

You can also stop checking them out using

```
git update-index --skip-worktree path...
```

This will stop git from updating the directory at all. Again, you still can add new file or a new content of one using explicit `git add`, but it will not even check out the repository versions. If the files are already checked out, git will leave obsolete versions there, so mind what you are doing.

See [git-update-index(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html) for more information.

---

It should be noted, that git is noticeably slower on Windows than most Unices under any conditions. On a sizeable repository, say 20 000 files, the first status after computer start usually takes some time on both, but on Linux once the file metadata are cached the status is almost instantaneous while on Windows it always takes a couple of seconds.

And it's not just git. Subversion status is similarly slower on Windows and the older versions that also had the metadata spread over many files were even more.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason it's slow is because Git needs to stat thousands of checked out files for many common operations. The stat operation is very quick on Unix-like systems but usually quite slow on Windows (depending on which API is used, but the quickest API has issues with modification times, timezones, and daylight savings time shifts and [can't be used with Git](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/114041)) and I think cygwin's Git is slower than [msysGit](http://msysgit.github.io/).

Deleting the files with `git rm` and leaving the history alone should improve the situation significantly. Having tens of thousands of files in past commits has zero impact on most Git operations.

Comment: +1, interesting link. By the way, was the kernel API (`ZwQueryDirectoryFile`) worth anything in the end?

Comment: @JanHudec: I don't think I got to any conclusive results. I recall having issues finding the right header files and eventually lost interest (I wasn't using Git on Windows myself). I probably still have the code laying around though.